# /ui2/cl_json=>deserialize doesn't fill structure

Tags: json, abap

I have two types of JSON: `result` and `error`.

I'm trying to deserialize these two JSON to my internal structure, but there's a problem.

Only for `result` the function works correctly, for `error` the structure is always blank.

Can anybody help me to solve my problem or indicate my mistake?

Here are my JSON:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "to": "to_somebody",
            "id": "some_id",
            "code": "some_code"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "error": {
        "name": "some_name",
        "date": [],
        "id": "11",
        "descr": "Unknown error"
    },
    "result": null
}
```

Here is my ABAP code (there's a screen to enter the JSON):

```
DATA go_textedit TYPE REF TO cl_gui_textedit.
PARAMETERS: json TYPE string.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  IF go_textedit IS NOT BOUND.
    CREATE OBJECT go_textedit
      EXPORTING
        parent = cl_gui_container=>screen0.
    go_textedit->set_textstream( json ).
  ENDIF.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
  go_textedit->get_textstream( IMPORTING text = json ).
  cl_gui_cfw=>flush( ).
TYPES: BEGIN OF stt_result,
             to       TYPE string,
             id       TYPE string,
             code     TYPE string,
           END OF stt_result.

TYPES: BEGIN OF stt_error,
             name   TYPE string,
             date   TYPE string,
             id     TYPE string,
             descr  TYPE string,
             result TYPE string,
           END OF stt_error.

DATA: BEGIN OF ls_response_result,
       result TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF stt_result,
       error  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF stt_error,
END OF ls_response_result.

/ui2/cl_json=>deserialize( EXPORTING json        = lv_cdata
                                     pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-camel_case
                           CHANGING  data        = ls_response_result ).
```

Comment: Didn't try your code, because the JSON is invalid (probably missing an outer `[` and `]`) and is not provided in a format that could be directly copied into a test report (I'm missing the `lv_cdata = '\{...`.) Please provide a minimal **working** example. However, your type `ls_response_result` seems wrong to me, because the value behind the key `error` in your data json is an object/dictionary but your type expected a table/list/array.

Comment: @konstantin I have added the missing part of the code for the OP (I added a screen so that the JSON can be pasted), so that you and others can test it.

Comment: Sorry but the `date` in your json seems to be an array (there's `[]` there, which is an empty array) not a string, moreover `result` does not belong to `error` in your JSON file either.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers. 
The `error` constructure shouldn't belong to `result`, that's why I'm dividing them into two independence constructure.
I mean, I can get only one of them, `result` or `error`.

Comment: It's still not clear. Can you edit your post and enter the expected result (possibly via a test code, as Florian did)?

Answer (score 4):

Revise your type declarations. There is a discrepancy in one place where you expect result as a JSON array (ABAP table) vs. a JSON object (ABAP structure).

This is the complete code I used:

```
CLASS the_json_parser DEFINITION PUBLIC FINAL CREATE PUBLIC.

  PUBLIC SECTION.

    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF result_structure,
        to   TYPE string,
        id   TYPE string,
        code TYPE string,
      END OF result_structure.

    TYPES result_table TYPE
      STANDARD TABLE OF result_structure
        WITH EMPTY KEY.

    TYPES date_table TYPE
      STANDARD TABLE OF string
        WITH EMPTY KEY.

    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF error_structure,
        name   TYPE string,
        date   TYPE date_table,
        id     TYPE string,
        descr  TYPE string,
        result TYPE string,
      END OF error_structure.

    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF complete_result_structure,
        result TYPE result_table,
        error  TYPE error_structure,
      END OF complete_result_structure.

    CLASS-METHODS parse
      IMPORTING
        json          TYPE string
      RETURNING
        VALUE(result) TYPE complete_result_structure.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS the_json_parser IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD parse.
    /ui2/cl_json=>deserialize(
      EXPORTING
        json        = json
        pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-camel_case
      CHANGING
        data        = result ).
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

Verified with the test class:

```
CLASS unit_tests DEFINITION FOR TESTING RISK LEVEL HARMLESS DURATION SHORT.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS parses_result FOR TESTING.
    METHODS parses_error FOR TESTING.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS unit_tests IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD parses_result.
    DATA(json) = `{` &&
        `"result": [` &&
            `{` &&
                `"to": "to_somebody",` &&
                `"id": "some_id",` &&
                `"code": "some_code"` &&
            `}` &&
        `]` &&
    `}`.

    DATA(result) = the_json_parser=>parse( json ).

    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_not_initial( result ).
    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_not_initial( result-result ).
    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_initial( result-error ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD parses_error.
    DATA(json) = `{` &&
        `"error": {` &&
            `"name": "some_name",` &&
            `"date": [],` &&
            `"id": "11",` &&
            `"descr": "Unknown error"` &&
        `},` &&
        `"result": null` &&
    `}`.

    DATA(result) = the_json_parser=>parse( json ).

    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_not_initial( result ).
    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_initial( result-result ).
    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_not_initial( result-error ).
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. My result structure is still empty.

Comment: Shared my complete code as reference. Maybe this helps you figuring out what's different?

Answer (score 4):

A JSON object `{...}` can be mapped only by an ABAP structure.

A JSON array `[...]` can be mapped only by an ABAP internal table.

In your code, the `error` JSON is a JSON object, but the ABAP variable is an internal table.

So you should correct the ABAP variable by removing `STANDARD TABLE OF` so that it becomes a structure:

```
DATA: BEGIN OF ls_response_result,
        result TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF stt_result,
        error  TYPE stt_error,                     " <=== "STANDARD TABLE OF" removed
      END OF ls_response_result.
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all for your advice.

I solve my problem.

The case was:
I get from provider two types of JSON: `result` or `error`.

I can't get both of them at the same time.

I need to deserialize them to my internal structure.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "to": "some_value",
            "id": "some_id",
            "code": "some_code"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "some_name",
        "date": [some_date],
        "id": "some_id",
        "descr": "some_description"
    },
    "result": null
}
```

Here's my needed ABAP code, which works correctly.

P.S: My mistake was that I worked with `error` like with an internal table instead of structure.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF stt_result,
             to       TYPE string,
             id       TYPE string,
             code     TYPE string,
           END OF stt_result.

    TYPES lt_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string WITH EMPTY KEY.

    TYPES: BEGIN OF stt_error,
             name   TYPE string,
             date   TYPE lt_data,
             id     TYPE string,
             descr  TYPE string,
             result TYPE stt_result,
           END OF stt_error.

    DATA: BEGIN OF ls_response_result,
            result TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF stt_result,
            error  TYPE stt_error,
          END OF ls_response_result.

/ui2/cl_json=>deserialize( EXPORTING json = lv_cdata
                                     pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-camel_case
                           CHANGING  data        = ls_response_result ).
```

Comment: I don't see the need to post the whole code. The only error in your code is that you tried to map a JSON object with an ABAP internal table, but it can be mapped only by an ABAP structure (and a JSON array can be mapped only by an ABAP internal table). Let me post an answer which is more concise.

Comment: I got you, Sandra. I corrected my ABAP code and share my solution, already. Thanks for your advice and comments.